# Adding django-pagedown to Django 1.5 Blog Comments

Tags: django, blogs, django-comments, pagedown

I'd like to add `django-pagedown` to my site's blog. I have a site, and an application called blog, built with Django, and I've implemented the built-in comments. These work just fine but I'm now trying to get `django-pagedown` to work in the comments. For example, if a user comments on one of my articles, I would like to be able to support markdown so users could comment with code snippets or formatting without using HTML (which I probably don't want to support).

I installed django-pagedown successfully with pip:

`pip install django-pagedown`

I added it to my `INSTALLED_APPS` section in `settings.py` and collected static files:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'pagedown',
    ...
)
```

`python manage.py collectstatic`

Something happened, because when I added this code to my `blog/admin.py` file the admin post preview window appeared:

```
...
from pagedown.widgets import PagedownWidget, AdminPagedownWidget
from django.db import models
....

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    formfield_overrides = {
        models.TextField: {'widget': AdminPagedownWidget },
    }
    ...
```

Since I'm not very familiar with Django yet, the docs at:

https://github.com/timmyomahony/django-pagedown

aren't enough for me to fully understand how it's implemented. Basically, I want to add this functionality to the user comments section in the blog.

I'd like to be able to accomplish this without making custom forms and just using the built-in comments in Django. Is this possible?

I was able to get this working but ended up going with [Disqus](http://disqus.com/) because it has great functionality and is simple to set up and moderate.

Comment: I just created a new proposal site on Area 51 for Django: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/58810/django-python-web-framework?referrer=9X6WkWFGnXadp17Pr161Vw2

Comment: The proposal above was closed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, consider carefully whether you really want to use `django.contrib.comments`; it's being deprecated in version 1.6 and will no longer be supported after that. See the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/HrWXBwe9BHU).

If you do want to use it, you're going to have to customize the comments app. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/comments/custom/) lays out what you need to do. In your `forms.py` you'll have something like this:

```
from pagedown.widgets import PagedownWidget
from django.contrib.comments.forms import CommentForm
from django.forms import CharField

class PagedownCommentForm(CommentForm):
    comment = CharField(widget=PagedownWidget())
```

You'll also need to put a `get_form()` function in your new app's `__init__.py`, and make the other changes described in the docs.

Hopefully this will give you an idea of how to proceed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I danced around what you have indicated without any luck. I actually spent quite a bit of time at the documentation link you suggested... I had similar code as you mentioned already but didn't include it because I thought I was on the wrong track (I wanted an unbiased answer)). I will edit my answer and try again what you referenced. Thanks a bunch for the heads up on `django.contrib.comments`, as well.

Comment: Happy to help. Any time I've tried to customize the admin, and ModelForms, and Inlines, etc. it's taken some trial and error and a dive into the source code. But in the end it works...